# How can I generate an XSD from existing classes where a List data type gets minoccurs="1"

Tags: c#, xsd.exe

I'm using a number of classes to generate an xsd schema defininition with xsd.exe. Naturally all `List` data types get the attributes `minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"` since that is exactly what `List`s represent.

In one special case however I'm enforcing a minimum of one element to a list in my code. I want the automatically generated xsd to reflect that design with `minOccurs="1"` because the corresponding XML file is created manually and forgetting the required minimum element in the list would lead to an exception in the application way down the line.

Is there any Attribute I can attach to my Property to manually override minoccurs as created by xsd.exe? If not, is there any other way to change the value without using post-processing on the completed xsd file?

Thanks.

Comment: Just to clarify without additionally bloating the question: The XML file is created and maintained manually and I want the editor to enforce the minoccurs while editing the XML file. Catching that easily preventable error after parsing the XML in my application is way too late.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the XmlArray Attribute (as explained by Lichtblitz) AND IsNullable=true

also see

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zds0b35c%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: I tried this before and it did not lead to the expected result (because it's not a single element but a `List` of elements). The article you provided, gave the answer, however. You need to use the `XmlArray` Attribute AND `IsNullable=true`. If you change your answer and nobody gets it first, I'll accept it. :-)
Thanks